# Dimension of the Zariski cotangent space for the non-smooth points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

I'm trying to understand the following problem:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic not $2$. Consider the $k$-algebra $A = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)$. For each $n \geq 1$ determine which $k$-points of $\mbox{Spec}(A)$ are smooth and for the non-smooth $k$-points determine the dimension of the Zariski cotangent space.

First of all, can anyone give me a clean definition of smooth and non-smooth points of $\mbox{Spec}(A)$? I have read on the Wikipedia that if there is an ideal given by some system of equations $g_1=0,\ldots,g_r=0$, where each $g_i$ is in the polynomial ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, then $X$ is smooth if it has dimension at least $m$ in a neighborhood of each point and the matrix of partial derivatives $(\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j})$ has rank at least $n-m$ everywhere on $X$. But what to do if on my example the ideal is given not by the system, but only by single equation $x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2 = 0$?

It seems to me that I understand the case $n=1$ but aren't able to generalize it to greater dimensions.

So, for $n=1$ we have $A = k[x]/x^2$. The solution of $x^2=0$ over $k$ is only zero, but $\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}|_0=2x|_0=0$ and we conclude that this point is non-smooth. By the definition of Zariski cotangent space at a point $P$ it is $m_P/m_P^2$, where $m_P$ is a maximal ideal obtained by localization at $P$. In a polynomial ring the ideal is given by the polynomials without free coefficient, then $m_P/m_P^2 = x/x^2$ which may have dimension $1$ over $k$ (I can't explain why it just seems to me that it is).

Maybe it will be helpful to admit that from general theory $\dim(m/m^2) \geq \dim k = 0$ and $\dim(k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]) = \dim k + n = n$ since $k$ is a field and thus of Krull dimension $0$.

Can anyone check is my explanation for $n=1$ true and generalize it to bigger dimensions? Feel free to provide your solutions and explanations.

Comment: In your case, the singular points are calculated by the common zeroes of all partial derivatives (and the function itself, but being homogeneous, you do not need need it). So, the only singular point is the origin and the Zariski  cotangent space has dimension $n-1$ at all smooth points and $n$ at the singular point.

Comment: Ok, I understand what to do with smooth and non-smooth points, but can you write more explicitly how do you derive $n-1$ and $n$ for dimensions in general case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algebraic set $X$ defined by $g = x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2 = 0$ is a subset of affine $n$-space.  Since it is cut out by one equation, $X$ has dimension $n-1$.  (This can be proved by Krull's [Hauptidealsatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull's_principal_ideal_theorem).)  At a smooth point, the cotangent space has the same dimension as $X$ (cf., Theorem 5.1 of Hartshorne).  At a singular point, the dimension of the cotangent space is "too big," which in this case means it must have dimension $n$.  (It can't be larger than the dimension of tangent space of the ambient space $\mathbb{A}^n$.)

As you said, we can find the singular point using the Jacobian matrix.  Since $X$ is defined by just the one equation above, then the Jacobian matrix is the $1 \times n$ matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 x_1 & 2 x_2 & \cdots & 2 x_n
\end{pmatrix} \, .
$$
At the point $(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (0, \ldots, 0)$, we get the zero matrix, whose kernel has dimension $n$.  Thus $(0, \ldots, 0)$ is a singular point.  At any other point the Jacobian has rank $1$, hence the kernel has dimension $n-1$, which is the dimension of $X$.  Thus all other points are smooth.

Your example is correct, but it's a bit hard to visualize.  Since $A$ is a quotient of $k[x]$, $X$ is a subset of the line $\mathbb{A}^1$.  The equation $x^2 = 0$ has only the single point $x = 0$ as its solution.  But this is a "fat" point as you observed: $X$ is just a point, hence has dimension $0$, but the cotangent space $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$ has dimension $1$, since $x$ is a $k$-basis for $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$.

I think the case $n=2$ is a bit easier to visualize.  Then
$$
A = \frac{k[x_1,x_2]}{(x_1^2 + x_2^2)}
$$
and $X$ is defined by the equation $0 = x_1^2 + x_2^2 = (x_1 + ix_2)(x_1 - i x_2)$ where $i^2 = -1$.  From this equation we can see that $X$ is the union of the two lines $x_1 + ix_2 = 0$ and $x_1 - ix_2 = 0$.  These lines each have dimension $1 = n - 1$ and intersect at the point $(0,0)$.